# Сбрасываются зависимые select'ы при выборе

Tags: javascript

не могу понять, как мне добиться, чтобы при повторном изменении select'а options не добавлялись повторно (чтобы этого избежать, обнуляю кол-во options при каждом изменении) и чтобы при изменении, например, year month и day не сбрасывались на 1. Заранее спасибо, друзья

```
<form id="date">
        <div class="wrap"> Год:
            <select name="year" id="year"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap"> Месяц:
            <select name="month" id="month"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap"> День:
            <select name="day" id="day"></select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

```
let formDate = document.forms.date;

setValue(formDate.year, 2000, 2010);
setValue(formDate.month, 1, 12);
setValue(
    formDate.day,
    1,
    new Date(formDate.year.value, formDate.month.value, 0).getDate()
);
function setValue(select, min, max) {
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        select.add(new Option(i));
    }
}
date.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    let target = event.target;
    switch (target.id) {
        case 'year':
            formDate.month.options.length = 0;
            setValue(formDate.month, 1, 12);
        case 'month':
            formDate.day.options.length = 0;
            setValue(
                formDate.day,
                1,
                new Date(formDate.year.value, formDate.month.value, 0).getDate()
            );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setValue(select, min, max) {
  const old = select.value;
  select.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    select.add(new Option(i));
  }
  select.value = old;
}
```